can i backup 2 whatsapp with two numbers to same google drive?
I have 2 phones with 2 different numbers linked to same Gmail account
Can I backup the 2 WhatsApp numbers to the same Gmail account?
And what will happen if I tried to restore one of the WhatsApp accounts? Is it going to restore the contacts linked that whatsapp number only or will restore all of contacted stored in the 2 phones?
Thanks

Backup and restore is linked to the phone number (i.e. WhatsApp account).
